# User access to tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am really new to SQL and I was wondering why I was not able to insert data into a table with a created user.

I created a user, granted him insert privileges on a table. 
I get the error that the table does not exist. If I try to insert with `sys` user I have no problem.

I am able to connect with the user and have already granted `CREATE SESSION` and `INSERT`.

This is for a school project and I have to follow what the teacher asks for. We are working on a virtual machine so I don't have much choice.

Thank you.

```
INSERT INTO Montagne VALUES (1, 'test', 12.5, 12.5, 3);

SELECT * FROM montagne;

GRANT resource TO director;

GRANT INSERT ON montagne TO director;

CONNECT director`;

SHOW user;

INSERT INTO montagne VALUES (2, 'test2', 12.5, 12.5, 3);

SELECT * FROM montagne;
```

### Copied from answer posted by OP

This is the result I get.

```
IDMONTAGNE NOMMONTAGNE ALTITUDESOMMET ALTITUDEBASE IDCOMPAGNIE
---------- ----------- -------------- ------------ -----------
         1 test        12.5           12.5         3
Grant succeeded.

Grant succeeded.

Grant succeeded.

Connected. USER is "DIRECTOR"

Error starting at line : 231 in command - INSERT INTO Montagne VALUES (2, 'test2', 12.5, 12.5, 3)
Error at Command Line : 231 Column : 13
Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 00942. 00000 - "table or view does not exist" *Cause:
*Action:

Error starting at line : 232 in command - SELECT * FROM Montagne Error at Command Line : 232 Column : 15
Error report - SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist 00942. 00000 - "table or view does not exist" *Cause:
*Action:
```

Comment: try `grant resource to yourUser;` and `grant unlimited quota on tablespace to yourUser;`

Comment: Please show the code you are running. This is really basic stuff and should work. Therefore whatever problem you're experiencing is down to a mistake in the code you're executing. However, we are not telepathic and we can only see what you show us. So if you don't post the actual SQL you're trying to run we can't spot your bloomer.

Comment: I edited the original question with the code. User was created in SQL Developer, Granted Create Session.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "schema" (in most cases equivalent to "owner") in Oracle? When you `select * from montagne` you are connected as user `sysdba` (it seems) - in the `sys` schema. This suggests the table is in the `sys` schema. Then you connect to user `director`. Each user has their own schema (their own tables); there is no table `montagne` in schema `director`. You granted access to `montagne` to this user, but `director` must refer to this table by its full name (including schema name); that is: `sys.montagne`. Try to insert into `sys.montagne` and see what happens.

Comment: By the way, having "user" or "application" tables like `montagne` (as opposed to just the tables created and owned by the Oracle database itself) is a very, very bad practice. Even worse if it was created following your teacher's instructions; the teacher should know better than to create user tables in schema `sys`. (If indeed that's what is going on here.)

Comment: Sounds like you created the table in the wrong schema. Presumably your  school project expected the `montagne` table to end up in `director`, not in `sys`. Also, the [`resource`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authorization.htm#d32061e9232) role is somewhat deprecated in the last few Oracle releases.

Comment: Director is not the only user that needs to have acess to montagne table. I used sys.montagne and it worked. For my own benefit, what would the best practice be since I have multiple tables that need to be acessed by multiple users.

Comment: Use the `grant` command to assign privileges to other users and roles as required. The `SYS` schema is reserved for Oracle internals so you should never touch it as you might break the whole database.

Comment: By the way, you can `select * from dba_tables where table_name = 'MONTAGNE';` to find which schema the table is in, and likewise query `dba_tab_privs` to see what privileges have been granted.

Comment: Ok thank you I will do that!

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps you might try to follow in order to make it work.

Connected as SCOTT, I'm creating a table which will be used by some other users

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create table montagne(id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into montagne values (1, 'Test');

1 row created.
```

Now, create a new user - DIRECTOR; I'll do that as SYS user in my XE database:

```
SQL> connect sys@xe as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> create user director identified by dir
  2  default tablespace users
  3  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to director;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to SCOTT, who owns the MONTAGNE table in order to grant access to DIRECTOR user

```
SQL> connect scott@xe
Enter password:
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> grant insert on montagne to director;

Grant succeeded.
```

Finally, connect as DIRECTOR and insert something into SCOTT's MONTAGNE table:

```
SQL> connect director/dir@xe
Connected.

Session altered.

SQL> insert into scott.montagne values (2, 'Test 2');   --> Note "SCOTT.", used to reference table's owner

1 row created.

SQL> select * from scott.montagne;
select * from scott.montagne
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL>
```

`INSERT` works OK, but `SELECT` doesn't. Why? Because the owner (SCOTT) granted *only* INSERT privilege on that table to another user.